# How to make a second backup on Windows 10

Tags: windows, backup

On Windows 7 I could easily make a copy of the backup files on a DVD disk. How can I do this with Windows 10 File History?

I want to make certain that I have an additional backup in case my primary backup device (an external hard drive) fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via searching "Backup settings" on Start and then adding your extra drive.

Personally, I'd recommend AOMEI Backupper which is free. You can copy files, make images of partial and full OS and user profiles, and ghost partitions/disks to other disks.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: I discovered that AOMEI Backupper creates a backup file with a proprietary extension. I'm actually looking for a backup that creates a zip or 7zip file so that if the vendor goes under I can still access my files. I guess I could go back to using the Windows 7 backup utility on Win 10, but maybe there's something better out there?

Comment: Oh yes that's a good point, one I hadn't considered. AOMEI appears stable but I suppose you never know in the end.

7z actually has this function but not in the basic version. You'll have to dl the previous release's command line version [here](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html). Then you can schedule a batch script follow [these instructions](https://www.organicweb.com.au/15111/general-technology/windows8-batch-backup/). If you're intent on 7z, that should do it. I'll say I haven't done this exactly procedure yet, however I do use 7z. 

Google "backup to zip" if you need something else

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in Windows backup program, which is actually the same as Windows 7.  Just type `backup` in the Start menu and it should appear as 'Backup and Restore (Windows 7)'.  It supports writing to DVDs.

While this backup option works fine, 3rd party backup tools offer a lot more options and flexability.  Many of which are free.  Just Google for them.